# Get String value of enum wrapped in Option if not None in scala

Tags: scala

What's the most concise scala way to do this?

Suppose I have an Option of an enum which could be None. How do I return the String value of that enum if it's not None and return null otherwise?

```
object En extends Enumeration {
  type En = Value
  val val1 = Value("value1")
}

val en = Option(En.val1) // or None

val strVal = if (!en.isEmpty) en.get.toString else null
```

Comment: Why `null`? Why not an empty string or why not keep using **Oprion*"?

Comment: for java interoperability

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
en.map(_.toString).orNull
en.map(_.toString).getOrElse(null)
```

But use that only if you are interacting with Java - `null`s are avoided in Scala so hardly any library accept them as a valid value and not introducing them yourself will make your life better.

Comment: I tried that over at https://scastie.scala-lang.org/59LtbZcyS86qMjTk14F15A but got a null pointer exception. I didn't realize the online interpreter can't handle null output. But this solution is correct

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you have a very good reason (read: Java interop) for wanting a `null`:

```
val strVal = en.map(_.toString).orNull
```